# Facebook Open Graph like action requires 'other' property

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I've created an action 'Like' for my app but facebook has created a required reference property called other. Regardless

[image: facebook un explained property]

Response without other:

```
"The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: other."
```

Response with other: false

```
 "(#3503) "false" is an invalid value for property "other" with type "Reference""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the other field should be the url to a video object you wish to apply the actions to.